# Valgrind: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value / Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

Trying to debug my C program with valgrind and for some reason it doesn't/can't tell me where the problem is and I have no idea what /dev/ttys00 is.

```
==25773==    at 0x7FFF2037495F: ??? (in /dev/ttys000)
==25773==    by 0x7FFF20240FFA: ??? (in /dev/ttys000)
==25773==    by 0x7FFF20249CF0: ??? (in /dev/ttys000)
==25773==    by 0x7FFF2026E8B8: ??? (in /dev/ttys000)
==25773==    by 0x7FFF20246EF5: ??? (in /dev/ttys000)
==25773==    by 0x7FFF20245061: ??? (in /dev/ttys000)
==25773==    by 0x100003719: print_node
==25773==    by 0x100003769: find_and_print
==25773==    by 0x10000391A: interface
==25773==    by 0x100003A9D: main
==25773==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==25773==    at 0x7FFF20246FDF: ??? (in /dev/ttys000)
```

Comment: If you're using `gcc`, you can compile with the -g flag to insert debugging information into the executable. That will tell valgrind e.g. line numbers and file names. I'm sure there's something similar for every c compiler.

Comment: That option has been common in Unix C compilers for decades, I'm sure they all use it.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer It does work for the bottom 4 but still nothing for the ones with ??? so I still don't know where the initialized value was created.

Answer (score 0):

the first 5 problems are in the device driver `/dev/ttys000`

This is a sure sign that your source code has a problem.

Please post your source code.

BTW: do you actually have a device named: `ttys000`?